# Share network from Windows to Raspberry Pi

Tags: networking, debian, ethernet, raspberry-pi

I recently got a Raspberry Pi, but the place where it's setup is to far away from our modem. So, I tried sharing my network via Ethernet cable on my Windows 8 laptop. I turned on sharing and set IPs and stuff, but it still doesn't connect.
The Windows computer can ping to the Pi, but the Pi can't receive anything from the Windows laptop.

Comment: You have to describe in more detail what you want to share. Since the Raspberry runs Debian Linux and and Windows there's hardly any automatic sharing. What services do you have in mind?

Comment: I wanted to connect to the internet. I switched to Pidora today because my Raspian was corrupt.

Comment: So, the question is obsolete?